# Dell PowerEdge R430 iDRAC8 snmp OIDs for hardware

Tags: dell-poweredge

can anyone tell me OIDs for monitoring:

- the power supplies of the dell server
- the disk and raid status

is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can typically find this information yourself by looking at the SNMP MIB files provided by Dell. In your case you can [find them here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YKG8D&fileId=3653612153&osCode=W12R2&productCode=poweredge-r430&languageCode=en&categoryId=SM) ([found on your product download page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/poweredge-r430/drivers)).

In your case, the power supply table looks like it's found at `.1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.600.12.1` and the disk status might be `.1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.140.1` (I say "might" because I haven't actually verified this)

Grab a tool like MIB Browser (for Windows) or SNMPWalk (for Linux/OSX) and see for yourself.

Comment: Hey Shannon, I already did a snmpwalk, but I couldn't find the related OIDs. The OIDs you provided aren't avaible, some variations of them neither. That's why I have asked.